# How to pass blank value instead of undefined in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this code

```
<script SRC="http://inuxu.biz/Inuxu_RAMP/Rhs?rpixId=283&p1={{category}}&p2={{product_id}}" ></script>
```

So this code is implemented on all the pages of my e-commerce site. On the home page it should return these values

p1 = blank

p2 = blank

instead of p1 = undefined

p2 = undefined

How to go about this?

Comment: "blank" as in "blank" or as in "" (empty string) ?

Comment: @pkyeck I think it is empty string as p1 and p2 are undefined.

Comment: blank as in " " empty string.

Answer (score 0):

this looks like handlebars - should work with an `if` statement:

```
{{#if category}}{{category}}{{/if}}
```

turning your code to:

```
<script src="http://inuxu.biz/Inuxu_RAMP/Rhs?rpixId=283&p1={{#if category}}{{category}}{{/if}}&p2={{#if product_id}}{{product_id}}{{/if}}" ></script>
```

Comment: the above code isnt working. doesn't work with a macro..{{category}} is a macro defined. any other way?

Comment: if it's a macro, do a `return value || "";` at the end